# Including directories in VC++ when working from multiple computers

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

In Visual Studio 2010, how to I set up my VC++ import directories so that I can build my project from multiple machines? For example, my project requires the use of a graphics library that's installed on both of the machines I'm using, but located on different paths.

I imagine the answer is some sort of macro, but I'm new to Visual Studio, so I'm not sure if my intuitions are correct.

I'm transitioning from the Matlab environment, where you can set the path directly per machine, rather than per project. Does Visual Studio have such functionality, or is everything at the level of project properties?

Comment: `subst X: c:\path\on\local\machine` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed use macros to set your include and lib directories on a per machine basis.

if you have your files in your project directory you can use:

`$(SolutionDir)\` This will point to the full path of your solution directory root

`$(ProjectDir)\`  This will point to the full path of your project directory root.

You can place your graphics library in your project directory and point to it like:

`$(ProjectDir)\graphicslib`, for example, or any other place you want to put it in your solution.

More info is located here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs.aspx

Answer (score 1):

use a hierarchy of property sheets, or use a tool like CMake to generate project files for you (as it should automatically find all the libs/includes).

For the property sheets: add the same property sheet to each project. Withing that property sheet, include other property sheets with predefined names. Then on each computer you work, you will have to provide those 'per-machine' propert sheets. For example:

```
main.vsprops       -> include by every project
|- matlab.vsprops  -> sets the lib/includes for matlab runtime
|- opengl.vsprops  -> sets the lib/include for opengl
```

Now in your versioning system, you provide a default for matlab.vsprops and opengl.vsprops that contains suitable dfeault values and a batch file to create them. This way you can checkout from the VCS, run a single file, edit the vsprops and start coding without too much hassle. For example:

```
main.vsprops       -> versioned
matlab.vsprops.def -> versioned, contains defaults
opengl.vsprops.def -> versioned, contains defaults
create_vsprops.bat -> versioned, copies *.vsprops.def to *.vsprops
```